# Normal vector to a plane; can it not touch the plane at all?

Tags: vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

On the [page on equations of planes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/eqnsofplanes.aspx) from Paul's Online Math notes, there's this statement;

> Also notice that we put the normal vector on the plane, but there is actually no reason to expect this to be the case. We put it here to illustrate the point. It is completely possible that the normal vector does not touch the plane in any way.

How exactly does this work out? The only way I can interpret what he said is 'since you can move vectors around without changing their direction, you can translate the vector $\hat{n}$ so that it moves out of the plane', but that seems trivial; there isn't any reason for him saying that there.

Which cases are being referred to here, where a vector normal to a plane doesn't come in contact with it?

Comment: I think that your interpretation is correct. But it is not trivial, often we would like to position the vector such that the tail is at origin. Physically the normal vector has to be on the plane, however mathematically what we concern is the displacement of the head from tail. One possible situation where this interpretation is convenient is to compute the distance of any point (likely be origin) to the plane, where we geometrically will translate the normal vector so that its tail will be at that particular point.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal: Hmm. So it *actually* doesn't make any difference if we translate the vector, and we do that all the time for ease of calculation, but we consider it to be an actual change based on semantics. Is that so?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think it strongly depends on the context. However, I think it does have some differences, but usually there is no effect on the calculation. (or the calculation is transformed into a way such that the reference point is at the origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the excerpt is from an introductory section about equations of lines and planes, the author is indeed just emphasising/reminding that unlike points, lines and planes—which are fixed in space— $\vec n,$ being a vector, is “portable” by translation in space.